# I have data at hourly basis and want to convert it into weekly at ssas cube level

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, dimensional-modeling

In my SQL Server database I have data at hourly basis. But I want that data weekly at weekly granularity using SSAS CUBE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a date field could you create a new field in your fact table view or calculated column in dsv? This would be a week key that would join to a date dimension at week level.

The data wouldvthen get aggregated up from the underlying hour data.